# how to make run an eclipse java project with scala?

Tags: eclipse, scala, jar, manifest

I built a java project and for the fun I included, after, a part of scala.
I use eclipse, and I used a trick for the classpath. Correct me if it is a mistake, but the following steps are required if you want to get libraries used by the final project:

1. in eclipse, select the project/ export/runnable jar/ and here you choose to create a dedicated folder for libraries. I don't remember if the manifest.mf file is also generated, I assume it is.
2. again in eclipse, you choose project/export/jar (not "runnable jar") and you clock on "next" many times until you can select the manifest : select "use an external jar", and select the file from step 1.

this method has many advantages for me:

1. I use javaexe, a java tool which allow to transform my java program in a service, but I have no main method, so generate a runnable jar does not have sense for me
2. the libraries are generated once, after, only the jar with sources+.class files are generated, it's more quick

my first question is : is there a simpler way to generate a jar with a generated manufest.mf file, I mean generated by eclispe. I think it is a basic feature for such an evolved IDE

next, my scala program does not work.
eclipse does not complain during code writting or compiling but the program seems to stop before entering in the scala method.
I thought at a scala library error, that's why I told you about libraries in the beginning of this text.
the situation is now that the libraries scala-reflect.jar, scala-swing.jar, scala-actors.jar,  scala-library.jar are in a directory near the generated jar, they are in the MANIFEST/MANIFEST.MF file inside the generated jar.
all this seems good, but my program seems to stop unexpectedly.
and since it is a service, I can't display the errors messages in the console, the only way to send messages is using a method I created, that writes lines in a file, but a call to this method at the beginning of the scala method does not write a line in the external file.

thanks for reading all this stuff, I hope you will have answers to my 2 questions!

Comment: for the second question : this is probably due to a problem of classpath

Comment: ok, that's what I found too, but if I make no mistake eclipse does not allow to export the classpath libraries in a simple "jar export", because the classpath is linked to the "run configuration", which is not needed in a "jar export". I don't know why.seems amazing.